# Get row between time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have rows every 3 hours, like:

```
796 4   0.9852  2015-04-12 13:00:00
797 4   0.1139  2015-04-12 16:00:00
798 4   0.5736  2015-04-12 19:00:00
799 4   0.0486  2015-04-12 22:00:00
800 4   0.3138  2015-04-13 01:00:00
801 4   0.9298  2015-04-13 04:00:00
802 4   0.9713  2015-04-13 07:00:00
```

...

```
1100    5   0.5677  2015-04-12 13:00:00
1101    5   0.8268  2015-04-12 16:00:00
1102    5   0.5761  2015-04-12 19:00:00
1103    5   0.2263  2015-04-12 22:00:00
1104    5   0.8859  2015-04-12 01:00:00
```

How to get 16:00:00 and 19:00:00 if Current time is between those.

Comment: The order of the rows is important to your question. Can you indicate whether the value `796 4` is just 1 column or 2? If the `4` is on a second column, can that column show 2+ values for 1 value in the first column?

Comment: Or is there ONLY 1 row every 3 hours on the entire table (regardless of whatever those numbers are)?

Comment: it would be great to have both rows, but even one is fine. 4 is user_ID, I want to get values of that user between two dates, so I can get whats delta value.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Can any row 2 rows of the table have the same time value?

Comment: yes for each user there is same time

Comment: I have update my question, forgot those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from time_table x
  join (select user_id, min(time_column) as time_column
          from time_table
         where time_column >= current_timestamp
         group by user_id) y
    on x.user_id = y.user_id
   and x.time_column = y.time_column
union all
select *
  from time_table x
  join (select user_id, max(time_column) as time_column
          from time_table
         where time_column < current_timestamp
         group by user_id) y
    on x.user_id = y.user_id
   and x.time_column = y.time_column
```

Comment: OK, can you remove user ID in where, so foreach user I get results.

Comment: yes but it has to be written differently. What's the first column's name `id`?

Comment: just auto incremental id, not to be consider for anything, I need to get third column for each user.

Comment: OK I GET : 
5 3 0.0166 2015-03-08 15:00:00 3 2015-03-08 15:00:00 |
6 3 0.0652 2015-03-08 18:00:00 3 2015-03-08 18:00:00 |

can we get just user id and third column (is called `value`)

Comment: Change `select *` (on the top and bottom query) to a list of the columns you want shown. The select list on the top and bottom query have to be identical though. (right now I'm selecting all columns via the `select *`)

Comment: Any way this is working, THANKS a LOT. You saved my Sunday :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget the table alias btw `x.` when you specify the columns to show. For instance you might want `x.user_id, x.value`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's always a row after and row a before the current time you can do this:

```
 (
   SELECT *
     FROM mytable
    WHERE `date` <= NOW()
      AND user_id = 4
 ORDER BY `date` DESC 
    LIMIT 1   
 )
UNION
 (
   SELECT *
     FROM mytable
    WHERE `date` > NOW()
      AND user_id = 4
 ORDER BY `date` ASC 
    LIMIT 1   
 )
```

Comment: 517 4 0.1535 2015-03-08 15:00:00 | 
6 3 0.0652 2015-03-08 18:00:00    |  here is what I get